# Is the Klingon language the only constructed language seen on-screen?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, languages, klingon-language

Alien races speak their own languages, Vulcans, Romulans "Rihannsu ", and others. Is the Klingon language the only **constructed** language seen on screen? If so, why did it receive more attention than any other? 
*I am referring to constructed languages not some gibberish words made up for one time use for certain episodes.*

Comment: [Related](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16788/3804)

Comment: Do you mean 'in the Star Trek universe' or are you just using Klingon as an example and we can answer more widely than ST?

Comment: I originally Star Trek. But you know, I am really interested to know of all other constructed languages which made it on screen.  I know Tolkien constructed languages  .. what else?

Comment: Darmok and Jalad at Tanagra!

Comment: There are several films made using Esperanto (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Esperanto-language_films), including some starring Trek actors (http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0059311/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I can tell, no other language has been fully constructed for use in Star Trek, or at least not to nearly the degree that Klingon has.

Vulcan has been defined to some extent, but it seems to be less than Klingon.  It is not, however, recognized as canon.

http://www.omniglot.com/writing/vulcan.htm

Romulan has been briefly described.

http://www.omniglot.com/writing/romulan.htm

Memory Alpha lists several languages, but most seem to exist only in a few words or phrases.

http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/index.php?search=language&fulltext=Search

So, yes it is the only fully constructed language seen on-screen.

Comment: It's worth noting that the fleshed-out Vulkhansu and Rihannsu are both non-canonical, whereas Marc Okrand's canon is - by and large - canon.

The reason it got more attention... Presumably because 1) Leonard Nimoy thought it was worth to get a linguist to construct a consistent language for Star Trek III. 2) Said linguist decided to publish books on it. 3) Klingon fandom, or "klindom", was at one time quite large.

Comment: Okrand's work with the Vulcan language for ST:3, why is this not considered canon?  Also, Okrand had to work from what James Doohan came up with for ST:1 for Klingon dialect.  It wasn't all Okrand.

Comment: brief phrases in Vulcan are spoken in some of the movies and maybe original television series, but not enough to form anything near a full language (and the phrases may well have been thought up on the spot to sound "alien" rather than be the result of a concerted effort to create a language).

Comment: This answer is confusing, because you're actually saying "yes" to the question that was asked.

Comment: @Plutor- thanks, fixed it.

Comment: Indeed; there's the Vulcan dialogue, which is canon, and then there's the Vulcan language, which is "fanon"; an extrapolation from the canon, done by fans. There's plenty of canonical alien dialogue; it's just that Klingon is the only one that fits into a proper language.

Likewise, many different writers have written Klingon dialogue, but Marc Okrand developed the language.

Comment: @jwenting: In the original series, several Vulcan phrases were spoken in ["Amok Time"](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Amok_Time_(episode)).

Comment: I would argue that the language of the alien race in Darmok is very fleshed out and "constructed"

Comment: We got culture and context in "Darmok," not syntax or phonology.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to address the part of the question: "*If so, why did it receive more attention than any other?*"

There was a similar question [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/16788/1604), but I do not like the direction of the answers given here or there. I believe that only the creators and those involved with the production could answer concreately. There may be an element of luck there, but there are **in my own opinion** some reasons to prefer developing a language for the Klingon rather than for other species.

1. They are aggressive and violent so their conversations have more impact than that of a soft spoken race.
2. They have lots of cultural traditions which usually get separate words to specify, so a vocabulary naturally builds up. And when the vocabulary builds up faster than that for another language it stands out.
3. People like to pay attention to the aggressive and violent. The OP here has the name "The Byzantine"; the Byzantine empire lasted the longest of all empires in history, and was relatively peaceful compared to other empires and ironically may be the least well known in the public. It is much less known than the Vikings for example.

And those I believe are enough to have given Klingon the advantage in being picked out for having a language developed for it.